# Why sp_executesql doesn't return results while direct SP call does?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is confusing. For this declaration of the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.JobGet
    @jobGuid uniqueidentifier = NULL,
```

This line returns results:

```
exec dbo.JobGet @jobGuid ='BDEA1E43-9EC7-42B0-A386-903FE1749FF7'
```

And this one does not:

```
exec sp_executesql N'dbo.JobGet',N'@jobGuid uniqueidentifier',@jobGuid='BDEA1E43-9EC7-42B0-A386-903FE1749FF7'
```

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add @jobGuid as a parameter when you call the SP. Without it the parameter will have the default value `NULL`.

```
exec sp_executesql N'dbo.JobGet @jobGuid',
                   N'@jobGuid uniqueidentifier',
                   @jobGuid='BDEA1E43-9EC7-42B0-A386-903FE1749FF7'
```

Comment: You betcha! Thanks! The thing is that I took it from the Perf Profiler  after tracing C# code. And the reason why that parameter wasn't there because I didn't specify `CommandType` to be `StoredProcedure`. So it defaulted to `Text` and thus was using it directly as provided. Man!.. Wasted an  hour for such a small thing.  Thanks again.